# I got a PHP syntax error and I don't know what I did wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress

I was trying to make a page so I put a post on a specific page on Wordpress and I ended up getting a syntax error. Below is the code I used.

```
 <?php /* Template Name: blog */
    global $more;
     $more = 0;
     query_posts('cat=29');
    if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
     ?>
    </p> 
    <p>
    <a href=&amp;quot;<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;quot;><?php the_title( '</p> <h3>', </h3> <p>' ); ?></a></p>
     <p>
    <?php endwhile;
    <endif;
    wp_reset_query(); 
    ?>
```

Comment: Check the highlighting.

Comment: You're missing a quote here: `the_title( '</p> <h3>', </h3> <p>' );`, but indeed, PHP should have told you the problem in the error message it gave.

Comment: what is your exact syntax error? ~(edit your question and insert it)

Answer (score 0):

A little indentation can help here (edited for brevity):

```
<?php
global $more;
$more = 0;
query_posts('cat=29');
?>
<?php if(have_posts()) :?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
     <?php 
        /* Template Name: blog */
        global $more;
        $more = 0;
        query_posts('cat=29');
        if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
     ?>
     </p> 
     <p>
     <a href=&amp;quot;<?php the_permalink(); ?>&amp;quot;><?php the_title( '</p> <h3>, </h3> <p>' ); ?></a></p>
     <p>
     <?php 
         endwhile;
         endif;
         wp_reset_query(); 
     ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

`the_title( '</p> <h3>', </h3> <p>' );` should be `the_title( '</p> <h3>', '</h3> <p>' );`

`<endif;` is that right?